# Is there a way to overlay react-navigation headers from within a screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-top-tabs

Wondering if there's a simple way to overlay react-navigation's Stack and MaterialTopTabNavigator components within individual screens. I need to overlay both when displaying components such as loading overlays and dialog/prompt components.

I understand I could define these components within the same root file as the navigation, however this means I have to track the state of the dialog within redux or some other shared state, which I would prefer to avoid in an effort to be more declarative/functional.

Can't find any good solutions, and I'm combing through react-navigation's source code, but if someone else has already solved this it would save me a lot of time. Thanks!

Edit: I also don't want to use react-native's modal or react-native-modal. Would like to implement a custom component myself.